# Set up BIND9 as DNS Firewall

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, dns-firewall, rpz

With OpenDNS now needing one to be on the pro package to have filtering turned on, being on a tight budget, we are in need of free DNS filtering.

After reading [this link on how to block domains with bind](http://www.deer-run.com/~hal/sysadmin/dns-advert.html), I collected SquidGuard blacklists and concatenated domains in the categories i needed into one big list. I then fed it to [this python script](http://pastebin.com/vtXzvwUt) generating a file containing about 2 million zones.

named-checkconf parses it just fine, but reloading named takes almost 10 minutes, then it wont resolve anything, and the server slows down to a crawl. Removing the include results in named working properly again.

Whats the proper way to set up BIND9 to work as a DNS firewall efficiently?
If it's possible to also block any domain that resolves to specific IP addresses that would solve the whole problem.

I'm running bind as non-authoritative, just a caching server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's out of date for current technology. In the BIND world, Response Policy Zones (RPZ) are synonymous with DNS firewalls these days.

A RPZ zone is a normal DNS zone, but is used to define policy actions by the server. The zone "suffix" does not matter, as this is not a real DNS domain. It's simply a zone file that contains a list of specially formatted instructions.

```
options {
          ...
          response-policy { zone "whatever.anytld";} };
};
```

The left hand side of the record defines the matching rule, with the record type and right hand side defining the action to take. Note the **absence** of a trailing dot on the left hand side of the following examples.

```
$ORIGIN whatever.anytld.

; destination IP rewrite
baddomain1.example.com       A     198.51.100.1
*.baddomain1.example.com     A     198.51.100.1

; send them to an existing A record
baddomain2.example.com       CNAME mywebserver.example.org.
*.baddoman2.example.com      CNAME mywebserver.example.org.

; NXDOMAIN it
baddomain3.example.com       CNAME .
*.baddomain3.example.com     CNAME .

; reply with NODATA
baddomain4.example.com       CNAME *.
*.baddomain4.example.com     CNAME *.
```

And so on. You can do quite a bit with this, including more heavy handed measures that risk impacting innocent shared hosting sites: blocking nameservers by name, blocking nameservers by IP, performing actions on the IP address of a returned record instead of the name, etc.

There's a lot that RPZ will do, and this isn't meant to serve as exhaustive documentation. Recommended reading include the Chapter 6 of the BIND ARM (bottom of this answer) for your version of BIND, and [Chapter 9](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch9/) of the online Zytrax book.

Cliff notes from my personal experience to save you time:

- Use zone transfers to move your RPZ zones around with`IXFR`. Enable `ixfr-from-differences` on your master to facilitate this. Use key based zone transfers if using BIND 9.9 or later to protect against NOTIFY based DoS attempts.
- Only let administrative IPs query the RPZ zone.
- Don't use more than one RPZ file unless you're running BIND 9.10. There were performance issues with multiple zones until that version.
- RPZ can't be used to stop the `NS` record based attacks that became popularized in 2014, as by default RPZ is designed to attempt authoritative lookups and not "betray" your record hijacking to an upstream nameserver source.

  - `qname-wait-recurse no` was added in BIND 9.10 and may allow you to use RPZ for this purpose. I've been meaning to lab it out.
  - Even if `qname-wait-recurse no` works, there is still a need for a record type that can be used to offline attack domains without extra configuration. I've spoken to Paul Vixie about this and we may see it in a future version of the RPZ format spec.
- `NXDOMAIN` and `NODATA` actions will betray the name of your RPZ zone in the `AUTHORITY` section of the reply. Assume that people will learn its name.

BIND ARM Chapter 6 links:

- [BIND 9.10](http://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.10/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch06.html#id2589604)
- [BIND 9.9](http://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.9/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch06.html#id2588765)
- [BIND 9.8](http://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.8/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch06.html#id2587964) (caution: BIND 9.8 reaches EOL in 9/2014)

Comment: I think a link to http://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.10/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch06.html#id2589511 would be a good addition

Comment: @Håkan I considered it, but RPZ differs in noteworthy ways between BIND revisions and it isn't a good idea to link to a specific version's ARM in this case. I'll add links for all three at the bottom.