# Spoof DNS request from a specific IP address in Bind

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

Lets say a user block at 192.168.1.0/24 wants to access facebook. I want the BIND Server to reply with a wrong IP address, lets say 172.32.1.1. But when users from the IP address block of 192.168.2.0/24 want to access facebook  they will get the real IP address of facebook.

DNS used is BIND9.

Comment: I think you want what is referred to as 'split horizon'

Answer (score 1):

you can implement this by creating views in `named.conf`

ACL for non facebook users:

```
acl nonfacebook {
   192.168.1.0/24;
};
```

and the view linked to your zone file:

```
view "nonfacebook" {
  match-clients { nonfacebook; };
  zone "facebook.com" IN {
    type master;
    file "<<your zone file>>";
  };
```

Comment: Pretty close, but rather than creating a `facebook.com` zone I'd recommend [using a RPZ zone instead](http://serverfault.com/questions/618106/set-up-bind9-as-dns-firewall). Stealing authority for the entire zone creates a slew of problems for the user, since you also have to define *all* the records the user might need to access under that domain and all of it subdomains. (odds of successfully creating all the necessary records are close to 0%)