# Intentionally Cause NXDOMAIN DNS Error in Zone File

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I have a server set up with a bunch of subdomains that all point to the same caching server, which is done using a wildcard like so:

```
*    IN    A    192.168.1.1
```

This works great, but I would like to exclude a subdomain from that.  I could set up another entry, like

```
mysubdomain    IN    A    192.168.1.2
```

but what I would really like is for that subdomain to throw an NXDOMAIN error.  Is there any way to do that?  Something like:

```
mysubdomain    IN    A    NXDOMAIN
```

I'm aware that I could just tell the server to not serve anything coming from that domain, but it would be nice if I could throw a DNS error instead of a server error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest you're going to get while staying within the standards is to create a "zone cut" at that boundary. This can be accomplished by either defining an additional zone called `mysubdomain.example.com` (which is more specific than your `example.com` zone), or delegating `mysubdomain` to a different nameserver entirely with `NS` records.

*That said*, a request for `mysubdomain.example.com IN A` is going to result in a response of `NOERROR` with zero records in the answer section due to mandatory SOA and NS records sharing the name. All records *beneath* that point will return the desired `NXDOMAIN`.

If you have an actual, *technical* need for making that one record appear to be a `NXDOMAIN` (and not just for personal preferences or aesthetics, which have nothing to do with the RCODE that comes back), you can set up a response policy zone ([RPZ](https://serverfault.com/questions/618106/set-up-bind9-as-dns-firewall)) within BIND that rewrites requests for that label. It's overkill and wasteful unless it's an actual business requirement.